# Any historical documented cases of language acquisition?

Tags: language

I am looking for *historical* documented cases where some person or group of people learned a (second, non-native)language (= gained ability to communicate) with no prior knowledge of the target language through being immersed in ~100% target language community.

This could be pretty much anything. Examples (random):

- a diary of someone who sailed with James Cook,
- an anecdote written by someone from Ancient Greece/Rome or by a medieval monk
- someone documenting some sort of invasion saying "Oh, they came and started speaking our language in five months!" -- so, quite literally anything.

The **duration** ("started speaking in *five months*") is most important.

**Important points**:

- languages should be fairly different (eg, not Ukrainian and Polish, etc.)
- the person/group of people should be older than ~15 years old (adolescents/adult)
- it should **not** be an immersion language study program (if a case from recent history) or anything like that, instead it should be a person with ~0% knowledge coming into 100% natural ~100% target language community
- the **duration** of getting from no knowledge/little knowledge of language should be **specified** (months or years, but better months); this duration point is really important.

I'd be grateful for any suggestions or pointers!

Comment: What about all the anthropologists who have visited the forgotten tribes?  Each of them will have published a paper that I suspect will include the duration of their visit and their challenges in learning the language; they're supported by grants that need to pay out the money based on duration. I did a quick google search and found some references, but I'm swamped at work and don't have time to follow up

Comment: What common measure are you going to apply when comparing accounts? _They started speaking our language in five months_ could be anything from exchanging basic pleasantries to full fluency.

Comment: What about babies, who at birth have no language, acquire their parents' language in a year or two?

Comment: @kimchilover looking specifically for second language acquisition, see older the 15 years criterion;

Comment: @KillingTime either one would work -- but "gained [a basic] ability to communicate" is fine, even if it's just pleasantries

Comment: Some cultures appreciate foreigners learning their language, or are just too polite. e.g., foreigners in Japan may be politely praised for their Japanese skills, even when every native realize they are outsiders at the first word and the grammar still sucks. Merchants / salesmen also are usually very happy with any language skill good enough to negotiate business.

Comment: @MCW Yes, those cases would work -- but (a) I'd like some cases where people were not trained in linguistics/ linguistic analysis, an (b) I still do not know where one can try to find +/- exact duration of exposure before basic proficiency.

Comment: look for Jesuit missionaries. In canada, brazil, vietnam, africa. Learned men, at doctorate level, who came to live directly with the natives and had to learn their languages. In many cases they were the first to codify the languages in written form including the first sistematic grammars. e.g, Tupi (they did poetry and ran schools in Tupi), Vietnamese (alphabet with diactritics). Probably it is the most extreme and self conscious  example  of exotic language learning you will find. And at least in Japan / China, some of them failed to learn the language at highers level of fluency.

Comment: @DaniilM.Ozernyi, please move your comments into the body of the question.  The question should contain *everything* needed to provide an answer; answers should not rely on reading the comments.  Welcome to the site

Comment: I have a shopping question vibe. Also, there must be a lot of non-historic (recent day) examples due to large scale immigration and travel around the globe.

Comment: What is "historical" for you? This happens all the time when people immigrate somewhere, or am I missing something? Is summer 2015 historical?

Comment: [Dembei](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dembei) or [Johan Gustav Renat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Gustaf_Renat) might be worth looking into.

Comment: Or [this other Japanese castaway](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daikokuya_K%C5%8Dday%C5%AB)

Answer (score 1):

Google [Daniel Everett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Everett),  he went and lived among the Piraha in Brazil.  He had linguistic training but no training in the language the Piraha spoke. It is covered in the documentary ["The Grammar of Happiness"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NyB4fIZHeU) where they examine the language and debate about its strange rules including a lack of recursion.  He doesnt give an exact amount of months it took to learn the language other than saying it took many years.  He also says he and his now ex-wife and children (who were on mission with him) are the only living Piraha speakers that are not indigenous.